# Unable to nmap but able to ping

Tags: nmap, virtualization, ping

I am using Nmap 7.92 on Windows and try to ping a Linux host on VirtualBox. I can ping the server and receive ICMP replies and vice versa. The VirtualBox host is using a bridged adapater.

I have also turned off any firewall in the virtual machine.

I have run as administrator and also used `nmap -Pn`.

```
C:\Users\user.DESKTOP>nmap -Pn 172.16.1.105
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-08-22 14:56 Malay Peninsula Standard Time
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 1.87 seconds

C:\Users\user.DESKTOP>ping 172.16.1.105

Pinging 172.16.1.105 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.16.1.105: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.16.1.105: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.16.1.105: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.16.1.105: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
```

Comment: This isn't a security question but a pure VB networking question,

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you ran nmap as an unprivileged user, so ICMP was not used for host discovery. Using -Pn "works" because it skips host discovery and treats the host as up no matter what.

Comment: Please don't use signatures in your answers.